# No more virtual MIDI devices in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, midi, oss

In Ubuntu 14.04 with `oss-compat` installed, I had this in `/dev/snd`:

- controlC0
- controlC1
- hwC0D0
- hwC0D1
- midiC1D0
- midiC1D1
- midiC1D2
- midiC1D3
- pcmC0D0c
- pcmC0D0p
- pcmC0D1c
- pcmC0D1p
- seq
- timer

Now, in Ubuntu 16.04 (just lately migrated from 14.04 to 16.04 as a new installation), I just have this:

- controlC0
- hwC0D0
- hwC0D1
- pcmC0D0c
- pcmC0D0p
- pcmC0D1p
- seq
- timer

The `midiCnDn` are missing.

I noticed in 16.04, `oss-compat` is provided by `osspd` (which provides `oss-compat` as virtual package). I though it was the issue, but after replacing `osspd` with `oss-compat` (the concrete package of that name), it’s still the same. I used `meld` on the new and old `etc` directories for a comparison, with no luck, it seems the difference does not come from a different configuration in `etc`.

Where does this difference may come from? How do I change what's provided? Is this a kernel option? Or is this really something I missed in `etc`?

Comment: Nothing in `/dev/snd/` is related with OSS. I guess you configured *something* in 14.04 to make it load the `snd-virmidi` module, and the update forgot that.

Comment: @CL. yes, `snd-virmidi` reminds me something, this may be a good track. As a side note, the update has not forgotten anything, I installed 16.04 in a new partition, using meta-packages and notes to re-create my previous configuration. Seems I forget something … Please, feel free to add your comment as an answer if you wish.

Comment: @CL., indeed, that was it, there was a `snd-virmidi index=1` lines in `/etc/modules`, I missed it. Your comment solves the issue.

Comment: Please add an answer with what you actually did to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

After @CL.’s comment, I could solve the issue adding an `snd-virmidi` line at the end of `/etc/modules`. After a restart, `ls /dev/snd` shows the expected `midiCnDn` entries. If one want to check it immediately without a restart, then a `sudo modprobe snd-virmidi` can do the same, but only temporarily. Adding a line at the end of `/etc/modules` is required to have this module loaded permanently.

If you want to have the virtual MIDI card using a fixed index, you can add an index option creating `/etc/modprobe.d/snd-virmidi.conf` file (required way since Ubuntu 16.04) then add the line `options snd-virmidi index=n` where N is the index you wish it to be at. If you have one real sound card, its index will be 0 so will want to have the virtual MIDI card at index 1. By default, the virtual MIDI card will expose four virtual MIDI devices. If the index is 1, they will be from `/dev/snd/midiC1D0` to `/dev/snd/midiC1D3`.

So there is a kernel module for virtual MIDI devices, it’s not related to OSS emulation.